# Making a nil value for unchecked checkboxes in Rails form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form partial that has a checkbox; if it's checked then the user has approved the message and it record their user_id in the approved_id field. When it's not selected, the value 0 is recorded for the approver_id?

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.check_box :approver_id, {}, current_user.id %>
  <%= f.label :approver_id, "I approve this message" %>
</div>
```

Is there anything I can do here to make sure it stays nil (or null in the database)? I'm iusing 3.0.10.

Thank you in advance!!!

xxx

Answer (score 1):

In the controller action that this form POSTs to, turn 0 values into nil.

`params[:approver_id] = nil if (0 == params[:approver_id].to_i)`